# Objects are not valid as a react child error. Found object with keys()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a method to render buttons dynamically and am trying to avoid code repetition by using renderButton method. I cannot find a solid solution anywhere to this problem can anyone help? I am fairly new to react native

[image]

```
   export default class DialogBoxStory extends PureComponent {
  state = { isVisible: false, type: 'confirm' }

  hide (type) {
    return (payload = '') => {
      this.setState({ isVisible: false })
      console.debug(`hide ${type}`, payload)
    }
  }

  show (type) {
    return (payload) => {
      this.setState({ isVisible: true, type })
      console.debug(`show ${type}`, payload)
    }
  }

  renderButtons () {
    return [ 'confirm', 'alert', 'input' ]
      .map((type) => (
        <Button
          title={`show ${type} dialog`}
          type="primary"
          onPress={this.show(type)}
        />
      ))
  }


  render () {
    const options = {
      title: text('title', 'Test Title', 'props'),
      message: text('message', lorem, 'props'),
      onOkPress: this.hide('onOkPress'),
      onCancelPress: this.hide('onCancelPress'),
      isVisible: this.state.isVisible,
      type: this.state.type,
      onRequestClose: this.hide('onRequestClose'),
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <DialogBox {...options} />
        {this.renderButtons}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: it should be `{this.renderButtons()}`

Comment: nope! still fails. It has to do with how I am returning buttons

Comment: have you tried after removing this line: `{this.renderButtons()}` ? does it work after that?

Comment: Yes! it still does not work

Comment: Can you try adding `return`  here?  `return <Button
          title={`show ${type} dialog`}
          type="primary"
          onPress={this.show(type)}
        />`

Comment: still no luck. I think this has to do something with story book

Comment: if `renderButtons` is not causing the issue your `DialogBox` component is broken. try looking at just that in story book with the `...options` you are passing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert all your methods (functions) declarations to arrow function like `show = () => {Your Function Body}`
- You have to call your renderButtons function `{this.renderButtons()}`
- Also this part of the code `onPress={this.show(type)}` has to use `bind()` method and pass `this` keyword as the first param `onPress={this.show.bind(this, type)}`

[Read more about bind() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)